# How can I write and reference global bash scripts which halt the parent script's execution upon conditions?

Tags: bash

I have written a simple script

`get-consent-to-continue.sh`

```
echo Would you like to continue [y/n]?

read response

if [ "${response}" != 'y' ];
then
  exit 1
fi
```

I have added this script to `~/.bashrc` as an `alias`

`~/.bashrc`

```
alias getConsentToContinue="source ~/.../get-consent-to-continue.sh"
```

My goal is to be able to call this from another script

`~/.../do-stuff.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# do stuff

getConsentToContinue

# do other stuff IF given consent, ELSE stop execution without closing terminal
```

##### Goal

I want to be able to

```
bash ~/.../do-stuff.sh
```

And then, when `getConsentToContinue` is called, if I respond with anything `!= 'y'`, then `do-stuff.sh` stops running without closing the terminal window.

##### The Problem

When I run

```
bash ~/.../do-stuff.sh
```

the alias is not accessible.

When I run

```
source ~/.../do-stuff.sh
```

Then the whole terminal closes when I respond with 'n'.

I just want to cleanly reuse this `getConsentToContinue` script to short-circuit execution of whatever script happens to be calling it. It's just for personal use when automating repetitive tasks.

Comment: Note that aliases are by default turned off during script execution. For something you want to source into a script, you should be using a function instead. (Even then, functions aren't exported to the environment and available to child processes by default, nor should they be: you should be explicitly sourcing whatever library defines that function and others you want your scripts to use, so readers of your scripts can easily find the places where the functions they use are defined, and so the scripts work even when invoked in contexts where your bashrc wasn't called).

Comment: Also, in general, bash doesn't control when your terminal program closes; bash itself doesn't even typically know that there _is_ such a thing as a graphical terminal program, being a continuation of a design from back when a tty was a [dedicated piece of physical hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Model_33) connected to a computer over a serial line. The idea of a terminal disappearing when the shell it's printing output from exits? Preposterous! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script can't force its parent script to exit, unless you `source` the script (since it's then executing in the same shell process).

Use an `if` statement to test how `getConsentToContinue` exited.

```
if ! getConsentToContinue
then
    exit 1
fi
```

or more compactly

```
getConsentToContinue || exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the PID of the calling script

For instance say you have a parent script called `parent.sh`:

```
# do stuff
echo "foo"

check_before_proceed $$ 

echo "bar"
```

Then, your `check_before_proceed` script would look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Would you like to continue [y/n]?

read response

if [ "${response}" != 'y' ];then
  kill -9 $1 
fi
```

The `$$` denotes the PID of the `parent.sh` script itself, you could find the relevant docs [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID). When we pass `$$` as a parameter to the `check_before_proceed` script, then we would have access to the PID of the running `parent.sh` via the positional parameter`$1` (see [positional parameters](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams))

Note: in my example, the `check_before_proceed` script would need to be accessible on `$PATH`

Comment: Note `$PPID` being a thing that exists. (Not that using it is a good idea; signal delivery is asynchronous, and relying on it in cases where one wants to stop a process before it does something specific a very questionable idea unless there's been effort to implement locking or gating appropriately).